# update the ribbon workbench in crm 2015 online

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, crm-ribbon-workbench

I updated the ribbon workbench in crm 2015 online. When I open, it showed me to select solution to open.

But then still telling me that there is a new version for ribbon workbench. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I closed all the browsers and delete history.

And it works!